# Limit calculation to last trading days

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am currently trying to write an indicator for Tradingview in Pine. This indicator contains several calculations in loops and therefore needs a longer calculation time.

For Tradingview this is not a problem. I do not get any error message. But it always takes a bit long to load when I change the symbol.

Is there a way to limit the calculation of the indicator to e.g. the last 20 days?
The indicator is intraday, but uses daily data as default. It is also possible to select other time units higher than the period under consideration.

Is it possible to use e.g. an if condition with bar index? How would this look in Pine?

I have tried to put the whole calculation into an If condition. But then there was an error because the indicator had no output and no plot could take place.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really limit the calculations to the last n days. That wouldn't work as you think it would.

Pretty much everything in pine has a history. Your script will be executed on each bar. Those bars that are covered by the last 20 days will be different as the time goes. Therefore, you won't be limiting the executing. You will be just changing your input data. But your script will be calculated on each bar anyway.

Loops in `pinescript` are usually not really needed. You should focus on how to get rid of your loops if you want to save some performance.

There are some optimization methods explained [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-optimize-pine-code).

Answer (score 0):

On historical bars, you can improve the execution time by running an expensive piece of code within local blocks with [barstate.islast](https://barstate.islast) or [last_bar_index](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_last_bar_index).

While `last_bar_index` tells the last bar index in advance and your logic can work on the fly, with `barstate.islast` you might have to adapt your logic to work backward.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © sbtnc

// @version=5
indicator("Limit to the resolution last bars", overlay=true)

i_resolution = input.timeframe("D", "Timeframe")

[resBarIndex, resLastBarIndex] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, i_resolution, [bar_index, last_bar_index])

if resBarIndex > resLastBarIndex - 20
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Ran", yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

On real-time bars, the code will execute on each bar. Besides, you might consider running some parts on a bar last update only with [barstate.isconfirmed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_barstate%7Bdot%7Disconfirmed).

These would all make sense if you could test the result, which you can do with the [Stopwatch Library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/xTHx0lQy-LibraryStopwatch/).